SQL query to group parameters into same column where ID is the same
I am trying to write a query that will groups several columns under one main column type called parameters instead of creating a record per parameter.
This what I currently have in my table called cars



car_id
car_model
car_lot
spec_name
displayMin
displayMax
state




102
Toyota
2
Battery
100
1
1


102
Toyota
2
Engine
1000
25
1


102
Toyota
2
Oil
90
9
1


103
BMW
2
Engine
2000
50
1


103
BMW
2
Throttle
20
5
0


103
BMW
2
Battery
100
10
0



What I am expecting is this:



car_id
car_model
car_lot
car_params




102
Toyota
2
params {(Battery:100,1,1), (Engine:1000,25,1),(Oil:90,9,1)}


103
BMW
2
params {(Engine:2000,50,1), (Throttle:20,5,0),(Battery:100,10,0)}



I am unsure how to write this query, I have tried using intersect but that did not work correctly.
I am writing this query so that it will be able to loop through this is a logic app on Azure.

I've gone ahead and removed the conflicting tags here; please [edit] your question to (re)tag the actual (R)DBMS you are using. Why does tagging multiple RDBMS products make my question unclear?

I made best attempts to format your tables, too, however, the first one came out malformed. When you [edit] your post to fix the tags, please also fix the sample data.

Do you really want params to have this wacko pseudo-json structure? Why not go for real json

@siggemannen it can be real JSON if that is easier. It has this existing formatting in an old database so I was just using that

Without knowing what data engine you're using, it's still impossible for us to comment. SQL Server on premises doesn't support JSON_ARRAYAGG as yet either, and in Azure it's still in preview.

@ThomA Thank you. I have re-formatted accordingly. Thank you for your help.

@ThomA, sorry, its using SQL Server 2022 on a Managed Instance on Azure

Here are a couple of ideas:
SELECT  car_id, car_model, car_lot, 'params {' + string_agg(concat('(', spec_name, ':', displayMin, ',', displayMax, ',', state, ')'), ',') + '}'
FROM    (
    VALUES  (102, N'Toyota', 2, N'Battery', 100, 1, 1)
    ,   (102, N'Toyota', 2, N'Engine', 1000, 25, 1)
    ,   (102, N'Toyota', 2, N'Oil', 90, 9, 1)
    ,   (103, N'BMW', 2, N'Engine', 2000, 50, 1)
    ,   (103, N'BMW', 2, N'Throttle', 20, 5, 0)
    ,   (103, N'BMW', 2, N'Battery', 100, 10, 0)
) t (car_id,car_model,car_lot,spec_name,displayMin,displayMax,state)
GROUP BY car_id, car_model, car_lot


;WITH data AS (
    SELECT  *
    FROM    (
    VALUES  (102, N'Toyota', 2, N'Battery', 100, 1, 1)
    ,   (102, N'Toyota', 2, N'Engine', 1000, 25, 1)
    ,   (102, N'Toyota', 2, N'Oil', 90, 9, 1)
    ,   (103, N'BMW', 2, N'Engine', 2000, 50, 1)
    ,   (103, N'BMW', 2, N'Throttle', 20, 5, 0)
    ,   (103, N'BMW', 2, N'Battery', 100, 10, 0)
) t (car_id,car_model,car_lot,spec_name,displayMin,displayMax,state)
)
SELECT  car_id, car_model, car_lot, (
    SELECT  spec_name, displayMin, displayMax, state
    FROM    data dOuter
    WHERE   dOuter.car_id = d.car_id
    FOR json path, root('params')
    )
FROM    data d
GROUP BY car_id, car_model, car_lot

The first one uses STRING_AGG to aggregate the params into your "old" style params string.
The second one does a json version of above.

Thats great. Both procedures work. However do the values have to be entered individually each time? More rows are going to be added and have to be displayed in params.

I've just taken your sample data. In your real query, you should of course select from the actual table you have?

Thats brilliant. That has worked (both procedures). Thank you for writing that

Is it possible to keep the column names in the params using AS? (spec_name,  displayMin,  displayMax,  state) in the second procedure?

Not sure what you mean :/ But you can probably just combine the STRING_AGG thing with FOR JSON if that's your game
